# Prove that colon ideal is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose $I$ and $J$ are ideals of a ring $R$ where $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Define the set $$(I : J) = \{x \in R\ \mid xJ \subset I \}\,.$$ I need to prove that this set is an ideal.

---

It's sufficient to prove the following:

(1) $(I:J)$ is closed under addition
(2) For any $x \in (I:J) $ we have $-x \in (I:J)$
(3) For any $r \in R$ we have $r(I:J) \subset (I:J)$

I have no issues proving $(1)$ and $(3)$, but can't prove $(2)$.

Comment: In $(-x)J$, give the $-1$ to the elements of $J$, and use that $J$ is an ideal to see that $(-1)J\subset J$.

Comment: @user85667 what do you mean by "give the $−1$ to the elements of $J$"? Isn't $(-x)$ just a notation for the inverse of $x$ w.r.t addition operation?

Comment: Yes, but maybe you have proven that $-x=(-1)x$. You can check that $x+(-1)x=(1)x+(-1)x=(1+(-1))x=0x$. Since $0=0x+(-0x)=(0+0)x+(-0x)=(0x+0x)+(-0x)=0x+(0x+(-0x))=0x+0=0x$. So, $x+(-1)x=0$.

Comment: @user85667 I see. Thank you.

Comment: Also, although it is clear, you should note that $(I:J)$ is nonempty.

Comment: Instead of (2) you can also prove that $0\in (I:J)$ and this is clear.